# Trigger click event with url parameter not using jQuery

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a click function on my page which triggers the opening of a modal feedback form when a customer visits my page using a specific URL with parameter.

Example: Someone reaches the website, clicks on a contact us link, the modal window pops up with the form.

I know I can do it using jQuery, but I would prefer not to. Is there a way to do this using plain javascript?

Here is the jQuery version of what I am doing:

```
    <script>
jQuery(function(){

   if (window.location.hash){
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
      if (hash == "foobar"){
         foobar();
      }
   }

});

function foobar(){
   jQuery('.modal-open').click()   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your latest edit on the question, you can make use of `load` event and [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method in vanilla JavaScript to achieve similar method as Jquery:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (hash == 'foobar') {
      foobar();
    }
  }
});

function foobar() {
  document.querySelector('.modal-open').click();
}
```

---

## Original answers

Assuming the feedback form you are trying to open is another HTML page, you can even do that without any Javascript at all using `target` property in `a` tag:

```html
<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

Alternatively, you can make use of `addEventListener` to do that without jQuery:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.open('https://example.com', '_blank');
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Click Here</button>
```

(The demo above doesn't work in StackOverflow because `allow-popup` is not enabled in `iFrame`)

Comment: unfortunately it isnt a page. Its a modal that currently pops up when a user clicks a button.

Comment: Hi @javapatriot, can you clarify and share more about how you open the modal now in your original question? Thanks!

Comment: @javapatriot Do you have sample code on how you open the modal now?

Comment: Just a jQuery version. I updated the post

Comment: Hi @javapatriot, updated my answer to include the solution for your case